# Does there exist subharmonic function satisfying the conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Does there exist a subharmonic function $f:C\backslash\{0\}\to R$ satisfying $f(z)>0$ for all $z\in C\backslash\{0\}$ and $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=\infty$

Answer (score 1):

For example, the function $f(z):= |z| +1/|z|$ satisfies these conditions.
Up to the [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function) of a subharmonic function, its [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian) in polar coordinates  $\Delta f= 1/r^3+1/r >0,$ where $r=|z|.$

Comment: Does there also exist $C^\infty$ function f satisfying above condition? I realized that I did not type $C^\infty$ in problem

Comment: The function from my answer is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} $.

Comment: Thank you .I mistook f as differentiable function on $C$